# Make Atom CLI wait for file to be closed

Tags: bash, atom-editor

I used to have the following simple alias:

```
alias bashedit='${EDITOR} ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile'
```

It opens `.bash_profile` in my editor of choice and automatically sources it after I made my changes. However, since I switched to Atom (i.e. `EDITOR='atom'`), I recognized that the `atom` CLI is non-blocking. That is, it immediately returns and executes `source` instead of waiting for the file to be closed.

Is there a way to make `atom` wait?

Comment: What is your intention anyway? If you not writing anything to the `.bash_profile` , why you are opening it in the first place?

Comment: @Inian if you have a blocking CLI, such as `emacs`, then it opens `.bash-profile`, waits for the changes until the file is closed, and sources them automatically. That's my intention, which doesn't work with `atom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that many Linux users find a lot of value in being able to quickly toggle editors open and closed for individual files, but Atom was not designed with that pattern in mind and the time it takes to load all of its packages is inconvenient if that's what you're going for. I believe that the *best* solution for this use case is to change up your workflow a bit to adopt a more Atomic way of achieving the same goal.

The package [`process-palette`](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette) offers a very flexible method of running shell commands from within Atom. It would be very easy to set up a system for opening and `source`ing configuration files.

Here's an example of a command setting in `process-palette`:
[image: The Process Palette configuration editing view. The command being configured is <code>source {fileAbsPath}</code>.]

And here's a command that opens a targeted file in Atom (for me, it opens in the same window, but I'd have to test that across different platforms in order to guarantee that behavior):
[image: The Process Palette configuration editing view. The command being configured is <code>atom C:/Users/stick/.atom/keymap.cson</code>.]

That menu setting provides me with a menu item where I can easily access the commands.
[image: A dropdown menu showing commands "Source File" and "Open Keymap".]

You absolutely don't need `process-palette` to open a file, and it might be a tad more reliable to do it via Atom's APIs, but in the case of designing a workflow to rapidly open, edit, and hand off files, I believe that it offers some configuration possibilities that power users would appreciate.

Finally, here's [a `process-palette.json` file](https://gist.github.com/DamnedScholar/7ab54c4bbca8c0d924cc664f1d7e38ab) (in gist form) that contains those two commands and can be plugged in by dropping it into your `~/.atom` folder and installing `process-palette`.

Comment: "[…] Atom was not designed with that pattern in mind […]", never thought about this. Thanks for the decent alternative.

Comment: It comes up periodically, because the type of person who is attracted to Atom and uses Linux is often familiar with (if not a power-user of) `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, and even `sed`, all of which support that editing style. But for Atom to be what its designers wanted, it had to sacrifice the lightning performance of an editor written in C with a completely CLI interface. As someone who loves the extensibility of the editor but is too much of a noob to learn the keybindings and language of an `emacs` or `vi`, I'm grateful for that. :)